# Changing UI from a background thread

Tags: ios, xcode7, ui-thread, background-thread

I getting an error that Iam changing the autolayout engine from a background thread , is there's a way to know which block of code makes this warning ? or I just have to search for it by myself ?? 
Thank you.

Comment: you can set breakpoints in xCode like this, and maybe it will show you the block of code makes your warning. [enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YLZVN.png)

Comment: if you're updating the constraints in your code just put them under NSOperationQueue mainQueue block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is a better answer but I would start by putting

for Swift:

```
assert(NSThread.isMainThread(), "Expected code to be called on main thread");
```

for Objective-C:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Expected code to be called on main thread");
```

to all sections of your code you're suspicious about.

This way app will crash if you're doing that code not on main thread.

---

Is this error an error or is it an exception? If it is exception you can try to catch it using exception breakpoint like here: [How to debug “Collection was mutated while being enumerated” errors and like, when Xcode does not provide me with enough information?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072549/598057) ?

---

After having looked at your exact message looks like what you need is:

> This code PSPDFUIKitMainThreadGuard causes assertions on UIKit access outside the main thread

taken from [iOS9 - This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread — where?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32680772/598057).

Comment: I have a project with almost 30K lines of code :D , I cant do this

Comment: Is this error an error or is it an exception? If it is exception did you try to catch it using exception breakpoint like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16072549/598057) ?

Comment: it's a warning , the system prints on the xcode's console this :
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release

Comment: See [iOS9 - This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread — where?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32680772/598057).